# Iterate on Groupby Object's fields

Tags: pandas, group-by, iterator

I want to be able to iterate on a groupby object:

```
    grouped = df.groupby('zzz')
    question_list = [a, 
                     b,
                     c]
```

How can I get a list of the values for the following:

```
    grouped.a
    grouped.b
    grouped.c
```

but using a for-loop?

Comment: Are a,b,c columns in your dataframe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either extract the keys like so

```
print df.groupby('zzz').groups.keys()
```

to grab grouped.a you would do this...

```
print df.groupby('zzz').groups['a']
```

or you can unpack the key,groups like this

```
for key,group in df.groupby('zzz'):
    print key
    #group is a dataframe corresponding to the key
```